# Putting focus on textbox not working

Tags: jquery

I have add text box in light box and i am trying to put focus on it but its not working please help.

```
<!-- First attempt -->
<input type="text" name="search"  />

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="text"]').focus();                
  });
</script>


<!-- Second attempt -->
<input type="text" name="search"  />

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){    
    $('input[name="search"]').focus(); 
  });
</script>
```

Both aren't working.

Comment: The problem probably lies in the fact that you're using a lightbox. You can only focus an element which is visible, so your call to `focus()` should not happen once the page has finished loading, but only after you've shown your lightbox.

Comment: @tianvh is this really like this? I have some in my mind that lightbox uses `display: none` what actually says the element isn't even there. Visible/Invisible (`visibility: hidden`), what could may solve this, is more like a opacity and can be selected very well. But im not 100% sure, excuse me if im wrong :)

Comment: @Dwza elements styled with `display:none` are still "there" (i.e. in the DOM) but they do not take up space in the layout, whereas with `visibility:hidden` it will still take up space but be invisible. In neither case will you be able to focus such an element.

Comment: @tianvh of course they are there, otherwise you couldn't use `display:block` or other display options after `none`. May i expressed my self wrong. :) So im actually right that he could solve his problem by editing his lightbox source and change the `display:none` to `visibility: hidden` ?!?!?

Comment: @Dwza No, the input must be visible to receive focus. Besides, the whole point of a lightbox is that it is invisible until needed to pop up and only then made visible.

Answer (score -1):

try $('input[name=search]').focus();